# Open more Tor Browser instances on WIndows?

Tags: tor-install

I've searched an tried many guide...but now, on WIndows, how can i open more instances of tor (also via batch file?

I followed some guide, that tell to modify the torrc.defaults file adding the control and the socket ports, but it does not work, and gives error at Tor launch.

I searched for a guide that permit to do it with Polipo, but it does not work too, and there is not more available the exe file for Polipo. I searched something here but without finding anything usefull. SO is it just possible to open more instances? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Tor Browser does not have that functionality.

I assume that this means that you want multiple connections to Tor at the same time.
Your best option is to download a free VM solution like Virtualbox and create multiple VMs with Tor running. Each VM will have it's own connection to Tor.

If are willing to learn Linux. You can also install a couple of Linux session in WSL and then install Tor-Browser in each of those and then learn how to run XWindows with WSL to make a GUI.

The reason that this isn't built into Tor Browser already is that the developers don't see any particular use case where this will help your anonymity. If you want, you can join the [tor-talk mailing list](https://lists.torproject.org/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo) and ask how to put in a feature request for a future version but for now this is probably the best you can do in Windows.